# Decode a Base64 String from JSONArray to Byte list in JAVA

Tags: java, json, base64

**I have a JSONArray that contains image files in Base64 format.**

**I would like to decode the images in Byte list.**

My json array format:

```
jsonarray:[{"manchine_image":{"image_file":"VW5pdHlGUw...}
```

My existing code:

```
 List<String> image = new ArrayList<String>();   
                    for(int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length();i++) {

                          JSONObject jsonobject = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);
                          image.add(new String(jsonobject.toString().getBytes("image_file")));
}
```

I tried this but i have this error:

```
java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException: image_file
```

Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

This is how you can decode a Base64 String to byte array :

```
import java.util.Base64;

class Scratch {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String imageFile = "VW5pdHlGUw...";
        byte[] decode = Base64.getDecoder().decode(imageFile);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**I found the answer. Thank you for your help.**

```
image.add(new String(jsonobject.toString().getBytes("image_file"))); --> image.add(jsonobject.getJSONObject("machine_image").getString("image_file")); //correct
```